# how to calculate separate averages for multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, where-clause

I have a table that has "months" as columns and "customer ID" as primary key.

I want to average all the values for each month separately for values not equal to 99999.

My current query for a single month is as follows and is working fine:

```
SELECT Avg([Table1]![Dec10]) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
WHERE ((([Table1]![Dec10])<>99999);
```

However, when I am trying to add the 2nd month, it is combining the first month's condition with the 2nd month's condition.

```
SELECT Avg([Table1]![Dec10) AS Expr1, Avg([Table1]![Dec11]) AS Expr2 
FROM Table1
WHERE ((([Table1]![Dec10])<>99999) And ([Table1]![Dec11])<>99999);
```

I need to have each month separate, i.e. calculate the average of Dec10<>99999, and in the second column, calculate the average of Dec11<>99999.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Group By clause in your query, and then you can separate your output by months.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be convenient to use use GROUP BY.

If you have distinct month values e.g. "jan10", "feb10", "mar12" etc. you can group on the months, and then check that the values is not 99999.

```
SELECT avg(value), months
FROM tablename 
WHERE value <> 99999
GROUP BY months
```

That is if you have the months stored as literals within a column, but from your database design this may be stored in an other way?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have each month separate, i.e. calculate the average of Dec10<>99999, and in the second column, calculate the average of Dec11<>99999.

In Access 2010, for [Table1]...

```
CustomerID  Dec10  Dec11
----------  -----  -----
         1      1      5
         2      2  99999
         3  99999      0
         4      3      7
```

...the query...

```
SELECT
    DAvg("Dec10", "Table1", "Dec10<>99999") AS AvgOfDec10,
    DAvg("Dec11", "Table1", "Dec11<>99999") AS AvgOfDec11
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Table1)
```

...produces:

```
AvgOfDec10  AvgOfDec11
----------  ----------
2           4
```